# PHP, SQL Check if the value is greater or less than the database value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code

```
$str = $conn-prepare("UPDATE users SET ss = ss + $sss WHERE user=? and $sss > ss and $sss < ss");
```

But it does not works as expected. If the value is greater than the database value or if the value is less than the database value, it should do nothing, otherwise it should add the value with the current value. The ss means the database value and $sss means the value we want to add. So before adding the sss value to ss, it would check if greater or if less.

Comment: Your question asks for OR but your query specifies AND. A value can't be both greater than and less than so your query finds no results.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$str = $conn-prepare("UPDATE users SET ss = ss + $sss WHERE user=? AND ss <> $sss");
```

Note that query *might* be insecure. You should make sure `$sss` is a safe value (such as an integer), otherwise you might be risking an SQL injection attack.